# Error al configurar strapi con postgresql

Tags: javascript, postgresql, strapi

Tengo los siguientes errores cuando intento instalar strapi y configurar la base de datos en postgresql, también lo intento con mysqlite pero siempre arroja los mismos errores, tiene alguna solucion, por favor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]